# Call a method from an invoked object

Tags: c#

I would like to create an instance of an object I can use elsewhere in my class without going through more reflection if I can help it.

After creating the object (either through activator or constructorInfo, I've read the arguments for both but used activator as its shorter for example) I have to cast it but this doesn't work.

**For example:**

```
Server instance;

public void A()
{
    Assembly loaded = Assembly.LoadFrom("C:\Program Files\test2\Shared.dll");
    serverType = loaded.GetType("Server");
    object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(serverType, new [] { "test" });
    instance = (Server)obj;
}

public void B()
{
    instance.startServer();
}
```

This gives an exception:

```
    System.InvalidCastException: [A]Server cannot be cast to [B]Server. 
    Type A originates from 'Shared, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,      
    PublicKeyToken=2a032d22a4688508' in the context 
    'LoadFrom' at location 'C:\Program Files\test1\Shared.dll'. 
    Type B originates from 'Shared, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
    PublicKeyToken=2a032d22a4688508' in the context 'Default' at location .
    'C:\Program Files\test2\Shared.dll'
```

I understand the reason for the exception thrown, but is there a way to cast instance as a Server from the type I want, ie the dynamically loaded dll?

Comment: Is `Server` in your code is different than "Server" from `test.dll`? or both point to same type?

Comment: Sorry I was trying to shorten code, have edited to remove test.dll and now trying to load from right location

Comment: I think you didn't understand my question. Is Server in your code is different than "Server" from Shared.dll? or both point to same type?

Comment: Server only exists in Shared.dll assembly.

Comment: What is the difference you see when you load same Assembly twice? both points to same Class `Server`.?

Comment: the problem is when casting it there is an exception, I am trying to cast to second type but at runtime interpreter thinks I want first type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On this line:  `instance = (Server)obj;` you need to specify *fully qualified name of the type Server*.

In the assembly you run this code, probabbly is present another type `Server`, so compiler tries to resolve this ambiguity, by picking local one. You need to specify, that you're going to cast to `Server` class of `test.dll` assembly or any other specific, like: `NAMESPACE.TYPE_NAME`

Comment: in my case they have the same namespace as they are in fact the exact the same class and in the exact same assembly, just in a different location. I need to use the dll in the other location as in there I use the assembly's path to get the path for starting another exe.

Comment: What is that "different location" stands for ?

Comment: I meant the same dll is in two different locations.  I am creating some plugins for another application and they share some assemblies.

Comment: Different location: means different namespaces (I immagine) => specify the *exact* namespace.

Comment: at runtime I wont know where it is, thats the whole point of loading this dynamically otherwise I would just hardcode the path that im looking for.

Comment: @user1584120: you wrote *Server*, so you know that type you're going to cast to. If there are different versions of it: you *have to* specify complete name of it with namespace.

Comment: If you load multiple assemblies with the same type, the types are not compatible. Instead you should cast it to an interface defined once in a common dll shared between all the plugins, and not duplicated for each plugin.